# Dup key add error on ZipFile object

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

I'm trying to figure out how to first check that

In my loop going through each file I have in a collection and trying to add it to a ZipFile collection, I've got:

```
using (var zip = new ZipFile())
{
    foreach(...)
    {
         var tryFile = Directory.
                 GetFiles(fileLocalization, fileName, 
                                             SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(file[0]))
              zip.AddItem(file[0], GetPathStructure(file.NameInContainer));
    }
}
```

The ZipFile type is from `Ionic.Zip.dll`

The problem is that `AddItem` errors out and I get An item with the same key has already been added.  So for example in the end it tries to add this key which was already added earlier in this zip dictionary:

> "C:\www\files\233272\Exercise Files\SampleCode\Original\MyTest.cs"

I can't get in a check for dup to work right...it stil tries to add this twice in the loop.

How do I check for any file[0] before trying to add?  I tried `LINQ .Any()` but not able to get the syntax right if I can even use LINQ for this.

I tried this but I am not doing this right syntactically:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tryFile[0]) && !zip.Contains(tryFile[0])
```

also tried

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tryFile[0]) && !zip.Any(zip[tryFile[0]])
```

also tried

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tryFile[0]) && !zip.ContainsEntry(tryFile[0]))
```

Answer (score 3):

Qu is a bit old, but since you're creating the empty zip and filling it, why not keep track of the filenames yourself ?
Create a `List<string>` , add each filename to it as you go, and use .contains to see if the file you're about to add is already in there.
Your list should be an exact mirror of the contents of the ZIP file.

After quick check in my project:

```
  zip.ContainsEntry("filename.ext")
```

should do the job. Also the `List<string>` that IONIC ZIP keeps appears to be

```
  zip.EntryFileNames
```

Answer (score 0):

Its long since this was posted, but I had the same problem, what i did is to make sure that the Zip file is deleted before you create the new one. I think when you create a new zip and it already exists, it just appends to it.

```
            if (File.Exists(file_name))
            {
                File.Delete(file_name);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old question but I needed to clarify. Ben McIntyre had it right. The problem I ran into is I was adding files from different directories with the same name, so checking if it contains the entry using the file[0] will not work. You must get the file name. I recommend using Path.GetFileName(fullPath);

```
using (var zip = new ZipFile())
{
    foreach(...)
    {
         var tryFile = Directory.
             GetFiles(fileLocalization, fileName, 
                                         SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
         var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file[0]);
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(file[0]) && !zip.ContainsEntry(fileName))
             zip.AddItem(file[0], GetPathStructure(file.NameInContainer));
    }
}
```